# Would getting a limit that diverges to infinity along a trajectory be enough to show that a two-variable limit does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Question says it all really. If I get infinity as a value when evaluating the limit at a given path, is it enough to disprove the general limit?

Comment: limits don't diverge to anything. they are not moving around. they either exist and are finite, or if you like, exist and are infinite.

Comment: That was bad wording on my part. But aside from that, would an infinite limit mean anything for the two path test?

Comment: If you allow a limit of $\infty$, then no. For example, $1/(x^2+y^2)$ has limit $\infty$ along the path $(x,x).$ But it has that limit along every path.

Comment: Oh, so if I understand it correctly, it's not possible to get a limit of infinity on one path and an actual value on another trajectory, correct? If that's the case, once I find out on my first try that the limit is infinite, I already know the limit doesn't exist in general. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, no. it's quite possible to get $\infty$ on one path and a finite limit on another path. For example $xy/(x^4+y^4)$ does this. You're missing the logic in our exchange here.

Comment: That's what I was trying to get to. In this particular case, if I get infinity on one path and a finite limit on the other, can I conclude the limit does not exist? Or do I need to have two distinct FINITE limits?

Answer (score 1):

You know that the limit is not finite.

Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$, and suppose you want to know if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists. Suppose $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = a$ (with $a$ finite). Then, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that for all $x : 0<||x-c||<\delta$, $||f(x)-a||<\varepsilon$. Now take an arbitrary $\varepsilon$, say $\varepsilon=1$, and its corresponding $\delta$. Then, from $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$, we know that there exists an $N$ such that $||x_n-c||<\delta \; \forall n>N$. Therefore, $||f(x_n)-a||<\varepsilon \; \forall n>N$. This contradicts with $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \infty$.